# Selenium TimeoutException in Google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run code at Google Colab, but it seems that there is TimeoutException issue when i use selenium to find elements. I am wondering if it is configuration i need to set up before i run the code.(I can scrape the info by using my local machine with no problem)

Reference:
[Pulling web elements using Selenium on Colab. error "TimeoutException: Message: " (Working fine in VSC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205494/pulling-web-elements-using-selenium-on-colab-error-timeoutexception-message)

I created a shared file for you guys to edit if you are interested in this issue.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13azNRjvRNaV7eQNwaTe26r0-LPye5Q_Q#scrollTo=8bY8Q5ZA9CZn

The first cell is the selenium's dependencies

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
#set up Chrome driver
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

#Define web driver as a Chrome driver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
#driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

The second cell is the selenium code for scraping out the product's title at:
https://www.ternbicycles.com/us/bikes#

```
driver.get('https://www.ternbicycles.com/us/bikes#')
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.agree-button.eu-cookie-compliance-agree-button"))).click()
import time
time.sleep(10)
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.title>h2>a")))])
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm also having this problem in colab ( while in my local machine my code works),the site I'm trying to get to recognize me as bot,and showing me message in html that I'm behave like a bot,did you solve this problem?

Comment: which webpage, i may take a look

Comment: https://israelpost.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A7/